# explode() and return data

Tags: php, irc

I have a string like this:

> :username!~tHesR5@tHesR5.users.quakenet.org

What i need out of this string is:

> ~tHesR5@tHesR5.users.quakenet.org

I have already got the username from the string using the following:

```
        $nick = explode(':',$get[0]);
        $nick = explode('!',$nick[1])
        $nick = $nick[0];
```

How would i do this properly to retrieve what is after the "!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that...

```
$strWhoIs = ":username!~tHesR5@tHesR5.users.quakenet.org";

$arrWhois = explode('!', $strWhoIs);
$strFirstPart = $arrWhois[0];
$strSecondPart = $arrWhois[1];
```

Refer to the documentation: [php.net/explode](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 0):

```
$nick = explode(':',$get[0]);
$nick = explode('!',$nick[1])
$username = $nick[1]; // <-- add this line
$nick = $nick[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `$nick = substr( $get[0], 10 );` ?